# Searching Algorithm: Product Knapsack Problem with goal to find lowest product above a certain threshold?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, computation-theory, np

I'm looking for people with some algorithmic knowledge who can help me out with this.

I'm currently programming a constrained tree search in java, where I want to have a certain amount of leaf nodes that is just bigger than a given threshold T.

I'm boiling down the problem (which is most likely NP complete) to this:

## Problem

> **Input**: a threshold **T**, and a List of entries **L** = [e<sub>1</sub>, e<sub>2</sub>, ..., e<sub>n</sub>], where for every e<sub>i</sub> (where 1 <= i <= n) there is a defined arbitrary maximum weight **wMax<sub>i</sub>** and a minimum weight  **wMin<sub>i</sub> = 1**. (wMax_i >= wMin_i)

> **Output**: a choice of weights **w<sub>i</sub>**, so that:
>
> - **wMax<sub>i</sub> >= w<sub>i</sub> >= wMin<sub>i</sub> = 1**
> - the product W of w<sub>i</sub> is greater than threshold (**W > T**)
> - the product of w<sub>i</sub> is lowest possible or if not possible is linearly constrained in T **(W is in O(T) / W < k * T)**

## Notes

- all numbers are integers here
- it will always be true that the product of wMax<sub>i</sub> **W<sub>max</sub>** >> T
- it would be highly preferable to find a solution where the w<sub>i</sub> are evenly distributed, meaning that I would rather have [2,2,2,2 ...] than [4,1,4,1, ...], this would be even more preferred over finding a solution with lowest possible W as long as it's linearly constrained.

I tried to approximate the solution when defining this problem with float numbers: every entry would be able to have a weight of **ceil(log<sub>n</sub>(T))** but this approximation doesn't work as the max weights are distributed quite unevenly.

Furthermore I read some articles on solving the product knapsack problem, but they were interested with achieving a max weight.

I'm also not so sure if this problem can be reduced to the knapsack problem, as the threshold is quite tricky to handle and I deal with products.

Edit:
I ended up brute forcing it by iteratively and evenly increasing weights until I'm above T.

Edit:

Example data:

- entries: [e<sup>1</sup> ,e<sup>2</sup> , e<sup>3</sup> , e<sup>4</sup>]
- weight<sub>max</sub> respectively: [3,3,2,5]
- Threshold: T = 15

Solution (nearest Threshold):

- e1 = 1, e2 = 3, e2=1, e4 = 5  (Product **15**)
- e1 = 3, e2 = 1, e2=1, e4 = 5  (Product **15**)

Solution (as balanced as possible, while also near):

- e1 = 2, e2 = 2, e3 = 2, e4 = 2 (Product **16**)

Comment: Can you provide some example data? Such as the List of entries, and the weights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an algorithm similar to your brute force idea.

> brute forcing it by iteratively and evenly increasing weights until I'm above T.

Let's do this, but using binary search instead. The algorithms goes something like this.

1. Sort by **wMax<sub>i</sub>**
2. Define `f(x)` as the product of **w<sub>i</sub>** where **w<sub>i</sub> = min(wMax<sub>i</sub>, x)**. See below on how to compute `f(x)`
3. Binary search to find **k** where **f(k) <= T** and **f(k+1) > T**
4. Find the optimal **i** to "split" the list into **k** and **k+1**. So **w<sub>j</sub> = min(wMax<sub>i</sub>, k)** if **j < i**, and **w<sub>j</sub> = k+1** if **j >= i**. We can to find **i** such that the product is just above **T** with either linear or binary search

To compute `f(x)`, a naive solution would suffice. But we can also compute the prefix product **p<sub>i</sub>**, binary search for **i** where **wMax<sub>i</sub> < x** and **wMax<sub>i+1</sub> >= x**. Then `f(x)` is equal to **p<sub>i</sub>** plus **x** to the power of the number of elements left (watch out for off by 1 error).

The product is less than **2 * T**. Also note that with this algorithm, the problem (where the product is not minimized but the variance/standard deviation of the weights is minimized) is not NP complete.